Building Alexa skill that does REST API get request
I am building an alexa app that should fetch energy consumption data from a website via API and API key, i have build a skill on alexa developer console,however i am confused whether I need AWS account for lambda function ? apparently it is built in the amazon developer console. Can anyone help with this ?
I am expecting for the code to run but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Alexa returns error saying "There was an error with your alexa skill response"
Here is my code, can anyone spot an error? obviously the api key and api has been changed for obvious reasons:)
`


import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


API_KEY = "BLABLABLABLA"
BASE_URL = f'https://api.octopus.energy/v1/electricity-meter-points/09090909/meters/2139898/consumption/'


`class GetElectricityConsumptionIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("GetElectricityConsumptionIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # Initial setup
        page_number = 1
        page_size = 15000
        more_data = True
        total_data = pd.DataFrame()

        # Define date range
        end_date = datetime.utcnow()
        start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=7)

        # Format dates for the API request
        end_date_str = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

        while more_data:
            # Construct the URL with proper query parameter separation
            url = f"{BASE_URL}?page={page_number}&page_size={page_size}&period_from={start_date_str}&period_to={end_date_str}&order_by=period"
            
            # Get the response from the API
            response = requests.get(url, auth=(API_KEY, ''))
            
            # Check if the response is successful
            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception("Failed to fetch data from the API")
            
            # Read and process the JSON data
            re = response.json()
            results = re['results']
            
            # If no results are found, break the loop
            if not results:
                more_data = False
                break
            
            # Convert to DataFrame and append to the total data
            data = pd.DataFrame(results)
            data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['interval_start'])
            total_data = pd.concat([total_data, data])
            
            # Move to the next page
            page_number += 1
        
        # Group by day and sum the consumption for each day
        total_data['date'] = total_data['date'].dt.date
        daily_data = total_data.groupby('date')['consumption'].sum().reset_index()
        
        # Find the highest daily consumption
        highest_daily_consumption = daily_data['consumption'].max()
        highest_daily_date = daily_data.loc[daily_data['consumption'].idxmax(), 'date']

        # Prepare the response
        speak_output = f"The highest daily electricity consumption in the last 7 days was {highest_daily_consumption} kWh on {highest_daily_date}."
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )`
`

# The SkillBuilder object acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
# payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
# defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.


lambda_handler = sb.la`


Writing Alexa apps is a frustrating experience, and I've come to realise you'll get little help here. About half of all Alexa related questions are unanswered.
Personally, I've found it best to do the following:

Run the python code locally and make sure that it works before deploying it to AWS.
Make sure that any external package requirements are added to your requirements.txt file (these will be logged in the CloudWatch logs).
Check the CloudWatch logs (in the console, go to 'Code' and then 'CloudWatch logs' - this will normally tell you where the problem lies. This is your best friend for debugging.
Include plenty of logging and exception handling in your code so that issues can be identified in the CloudWatch logs easily.
Have ChatGPT help you, it will greatly streamline the process and can often identify the processes required, dependencies, syntax and much more.

And FYI, if you're planning to publish this, I've not found any reliable way to enter an API key into the skill. There are no text inputs or advanced settings, or seemingly any way to feed this to the skill that I am aware of.
Best of luck, you will need it.

Thank you so much ! i agree, there is not much help available ! This alexa building task is just an experimental one as i work in a lab and this is what they want me to build. So this is not going to be deployed ! Thanks for the good luck i do need it :D
